# How to add key-value pairs to a list without adding sublists?

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension

this is probably a simpler question but I just don't seem to get how to do it.
I have a list with strings, e.g.

`my_list = ["a_foo", "b_foo"]`.

And I have a dictionary with keys as strings and my values are lists that contain strings, e.g.

`my_dict = {"key_foo": ["a_bar"], "another_foo": ["c_bar", "False"]}`.

I tried to write a list comprehension that appends all key-value pairs to my existing list when the list does not contain "False". This is it

```
my_list.extend([[key, value] for (key, value) in my_dict.items() if 'False' not in value])
```

I get the output `["a_foo", "b_foo", ["key_foo", ["a_bar"]]]`. I absolutely understand why this is happening, however, I have not been able to find a way to make the output look like this instead: `["a_foo", "b_foo", "key_foo", ["a_bar"]]`. Could someone please explain how to do it? I would really appreciate it!

Comment: The output you want is not valid Python.  In fact, the output you claim to get isn't either.

Comment: I'm sorry, I corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close to the result with list comprehensions. Once you have filtered on values that do not contain `'False'`, you just have to iterate over the tuple `(key, values)`, that is return the `key` then the `values`:

```
>>> my_list = ["a_foo", "b_foo"]
>>> my_dict = {"key_foo": ["a_bar"], "another_foo": ["c_bar", "False"]}
>>> my_list.extend([e for k, vs in my_dict.items() if 'False' not in vs for e in (k, vs)])
>>> my_list
['a_foo', 'b_foo', 'key_foo', ['a_bar']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a modification of your code to do this:

```py
my_list = ["a_foo", "b_foo"]
my_dict = {"key_foo": ["a_bar"], "another_foo": ["c_bar", "False"]}

[my_list.extend([key, value]) for (key, value) in my_dict.items() if 'False' not in value]
```

Doing it in multiple lines also work:

```py
my_list = ["a_foo", "b_foo"]
my_dict = {"key_foo": ["a_bar"], "another_foo": ["c_bar", "False"]}

for (key, value) in my_dict.items(): 
    if 'False' not in value:
        my_list.extend([key, value])
```

When you do it in multiple lines, it is clearer now why your original code did not work. It is because the previous code appends each key-value pair as one element, and what we wanted to achieve was to append the key and the value as two separate elements. Moving the `extend` method into the inner loop prevents using the key-value pair as one element.

Edit:

This is how to do it in list comprehension by "flatening" the array instead

```py
my_list = ["a_foo", "b_foo"]
my_dict = {"key_foo": ["a_bar"], "another_foo": ["c_bar", "False"]}

my_list.extend([i for pair in my_dict.items() for i in pair if "False" not in pair[1]])
```

Comment: Thank you very much. :) So just to be clear: It could not have worked with a list comprehension either way?

Comment: You can do that by "flatening" the list of lists. See my updated answer.

Comment: First version: please do not use a list comprehension to perform a side effect. See : https://stackoverflow.com/a/5753614/6914441